# Download-Page with JQuery request

Tags: php, jquery

I have a download page. Members are free to click on their bought songs and the download starts. I wish now that in the same time an Ajax request takes place, which adjusts the count of downloads in the database. The page should then be reloaded to the counter from the database is updated again. If the counter is zero, there is no longer downloading.
Obviously my script does not work. The download happens, but the JQuery-Script will not work. Does someone have a solution?

This is the link to the download-page:

```
<a href="get-download-files.php?file=xyz.zip"><img class="a_0" src="images/download.png" width="30" height="30" />XYZ-Song/a>
```

And this is the Java-Script on the same page:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".a_0").click(function(){
        $.get("zaehler.php?dl_id=1", function(data){
            $("#ausgabe").html(data);
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

And this is the request-file:

```
<?php 
require_once 'includes/db_login.php';
$dl_id = $_REQUEST['dl_id'];

// counter updaten
$sql = 'UPDATE ' . $tbl_prefix . 'downloads 
        SET zaehler   = zaehler - 1                
        WHERE dl_id  = ' .$dl_id;
mysql_query($sql);
$abfrage = 'SELECT zaehler FROM ' . $tbl_prefix . 'downloads WHERE dl_id=' . $dl_id;
$ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage);
while ($datensatz = mysql_fetch_array($ergebnis, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo '<h3 style="color:#333;">Dein Download-Stand</h2>';
    echo '<br /><br />Du hast noch ' . $datensatz['zaehler'] . ' Downloads zugut.'; 
}
?>
```

Im thanking you. Best regards,
Heinz

Comment: Yes, this could be done, but it can be easily tricked into allowing the user to download as many times as they want unless you instead update the database on the `get-download-files.php?file=xyz.zip` script.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Ajax for this. In the script get-download-files.php, update the database before delivering the file to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".a_0").click(function(){
        $("#ausgabe").load("zaehler.php?dl_id=1");
    });

});
</script>
```

You can check if your code is executed by adding a alert() inside your function. If the alert fires, the function is executed.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".a_0").click(function(){
        alert('Function is fired!'); // Debug
        $("#ausgabe").load("zaehler.php?dl_id=1");
    });

});
</script>
```